# How to transfer HTML datetime picker datetime-local to moment format

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, datetime, datetimepicker

I have an input type :

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="sdTime" id="stTimeID" onChange={this.stDateTime} />
```

and a date format:

```
const dateFormat = 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss a';
```

I want to transfer this input type to this string format and put it to moment:

```
'01/14/2020 09:00:00 am'
```

```
const fromDate = moment('01/14/2020 09:00:00 am', dateFormat);
```

How can I do it? Thank you!

Comment: you want to convert your date to particulate format ??? or what

Comment: @PrakashKarena I've solved it, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution for it.
Using moment:

```
const testst = moment(stDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss a');
```

Hope it will be help :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the datetime-local only takes the 24-hour date-time format, you can use this for converting a ISO datetime string:

```
moment(yourIsoDateStr).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
```

Or this for a new date object

```
moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
```